# How to set the alpha value for matplotlib plots globally

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alpha

Using Jupyther Notebooks i often find myself repeadily writing the following to change the alpha value of the plots:

```
plot(x,y1, alpha=.6)
plot(x,y2, alpha=.6)
...
```

I was hoping to find a matching value in the rcParameters to change to option globally like:

```
plt.rcParams['lines.alpha'] = 0.6 #not working
```

What is a possible workaround to change the alpha value for all plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question with help of the matplotlib team the following code will do the job by changeing the alpha value of the line colors globally:

```
alpha = 0.6
to_rgba = matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter().to_rgba

for i, col in enumerate(plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']):
    plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'][i] = to_rgba(col, alpha)
```

Note: In matplotlib 1.5 `color_cycle` will be deprecated and replaced by `prop_cycle`

The ability the set the alpha value over the rcParams has also been added to the wishlist for Version 2.1

Comment: They replied faster than I would of believed!

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, based on their [How to](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html) entry:

> If you need all the figure elements to be transparent, there is currently no global alpha setting, but you can set the alpha channel on individual elements.

So, via matplotlib ***there's currently no way to do this***.

---

What I usually do for global values is define an external configuration file, define values and import them to the appropriate scripts.

**my_conf.py**

```
# Parameters:

# matplotlib alpha
ALPHA = .6
```

**my_plots.py**

```
import conf.py as CONF

plot(x,y1, alpha=CONF.ALPHA)
plot(x,y2, alpha=CONF.ALPHA)
```

This usually helps in keeping configuration separated and easy to update.

Comment: I was afraid so. My main intention was to keep the code short and readable as it is used in a notebook. So your solution does not help me much in this situation, as it also implies the repeatedly use of the alpha argument in the plot command

Comment: I understand, I just offered an alternative to make the answer a bit more complete for possible future wanderers. I'm not sure why you cannot set it, but, you can always [submit it](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/labels/wishlist) as a **wish** if you have the time **and** patience.

Comment: Yes, thanks for bringing up the HowTo entry. Based on that I submitted a  [feature request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5132)

Comment: Good luck. If they actually have a good workaround (that I don't know of) be sure to come back and post it as your solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated version (perhaps cleaner available) :

```
from cycler import cycler
alpha = 0.5
to_rgba = matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter().to_rgba#
color_list=[]
for i, col in enumerate(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']):
    color_list.append(to_rgba(col['color'], alpha))
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=color_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is just to specify the alpha and pass this to the rcParams

```
    plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(alpha=[0.5])
```

Bear in mind that this can be combined with any other cycling properties such as the color and line style.

```
    cyc_color = cycler(color=['r','b','g')
    cyc_lines = cycler(linestyle=['-', '--', ':'])
    cyc_alpha = cycler(alpha=[0.5, 0.3])
    cyc = (cyc_alpha * cyc_lines * cyc_color)
```

Be careful with the order of your cyclers, as the sequence above will cycle through colors, then lines, then alphas.